# i can't Send Mail Using Contact Form With PHPMailer and Gmail SMTP

Tags: php, html, email

I'm trying to send an email from contact by using PHPMailer and Gmail SMTP, I actually don't know where is the issue? 
I download [PHPMailer from githup.](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
I tried to do it as [this gay did.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37tSrPc983s&t=608s)

**contact.html**

```
  <form action="contact.php" method="POST" class="p-5 ">
            <div class="row form-group">
              <div class=" mb-3 ">
                <label class="text-black" for="first-name">الاسم الاول</label>
                <input type="text" name="first-name" class="form-control" />
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <label class="text-black" for="last-name">الاسم الاخير</label>
                <input type="text" name="last-name" class="form-control" />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col">
                <label class="text-black" for="email">إيميل</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col">
                <label class="text-black" for="subject">الموضوع</label>
                <input type="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col">
                <label class="text-black" for="message"
                  >محتوى الرسالة</label
                >
                <textarea
                  name="message"
                  cols="30"
                  rows="7"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="اكتب هنا ..."
                ></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col2">
                <input
                  type="submit"
                  name="submit"
                  value="إرسال"
                  class="px-4 text-white"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

**contact.php**

```
 <?php

       $result="";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port=587;
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;

$mail->SMTPSecure='tls'; 
$mail->Username='secret';
$mail->Password='secret';

$mail->setForm($_POST['email'],$_POST['first-name']);
$mail->addAddress('secret');
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'],$_POST['last-name']);


$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->subject='Contact Us: '.$_POST['subject'];
$mail->Body='<h1 align=center>الأسم :'.$_POST['first-name'].$_POST['last-name'].' الايميل: '.$_POST['email'].' العنوان: '.$_POST['subject'].' العنوان: '.$_POST['message'].'</h1>';

if(!$mail->send()){
    $result="حدث خطاء حاول مرة اخرى ، وشكراً";
}
else{
    $result="شكراً".$_POST['fname']."لتواصلك معنا ،سيتم الرد عليكم 
        قريباً";
  } 
 }
 ?>
```

the error message page  Doesn't exist

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 step verification enabled for your gmail account, gmail won't allow you to send email through your app. You have to generate app password and use it to send mails. Check here how to generate app password to use from third party apps. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: it's actually disable , i don't really know what the actual problem , when i click submit it's must got to contact.php and send the email but it's come back as "page not found " , even if it's live on my domain !!!

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem but i didn't understand why ,
in line 18 in the php file ,
$mail->setForm($_POST['email'],$_POST['first-name']);
if i remove it i can send the email to my gmail account.
can anyone tell what is that about ?
and if the message in arabica language , it will not read it?